# Cannot get PhpStorm to compare deployed files folder with local

Tags: phpstorm

Am following:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.3/comparing-deployed-files-and-folders-with-their-local-versions.html

I have my server setup in the remote host, and can see my directory, folders and files.

I would like to compare a whole folder on my local machine with what is on the server.

It works for individual files, but my developer has changed a whole load of files in the directory.

Please see screenshots.

1. I try and compare a directory from Remote host to the local server (see screenshot)
2. Says I failed to download the content of the file (...name of folder) - see screenshot
3. I try and compare one file (screenshot)
4. Works fine

How do I compare an entire folder, and see what has been changed?

[image: TRY COMPARE FOLDERS]

[image: GET ERROR]

[image: TRY COMPARE FILE]

[image: WORKS OK - CAN SEE DIFFERENCES]

Comment: 1) Try other way around -- comparing local to remote; 2) Ensure that local or remote folder is not a symlink -- only "real" files; 3) **(most important)** Please use `Sync with XXX` instead -- it works fine with folders and allows you to see all that info (has diff window built-in)

Comment: There is only an option 'Compare Directory With'... with offers a local directory. No option to compare to directory on server.

Comment: Screenshot? That one that I mentioned is `Deployment | Sync with Deployed` if invoked from Project View panel; From Remote Host panel it's `Sync With Local...`

Comment: There is no option from Deployment | Sync with Deployed? http://imgur.com/a/6mRVg

Comment: And from the other side -->  http://imgur.com/a/n0n0E

Comment: What do you mean "there is no such option"? What do I see on your screenshots then (especially last one)? Why do I see "Sync with Deployed to..." (middle) and "Deployment" (bottom)? If they do not work then maybe your Deployment is not configured properly -- I do use such action almost every other day.

Comment: Ah - So. This will not actually 'sync' but do a compare?

Answer (score 1):

As per **official documentation** from the link you have provided:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.3/comparing-deployed-files-and-folders-with-their-local-versions.html#d30440e104

> **Comparing a remote folder with its local version**
>
> 1. Open the Remote Host tool window.
> 2. Select the folder in question. Then choose **Tools | Deployment | Sync with Local** on the main menu or **Sync with local** on the context menu of the selection.
> 3. In the **Differences Viewer for Folders** that opens, explore the differences and synchronize the files, where applicable.

---

The same but when invoked from Project View panel:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.3/comparing-deployed-files-and-folders-with-their-local-versions.html#d30440e154

> **Comparing a local folder with its remote version**
>
> This action is available only if you have a default server access configuration appointed.
>
> 1. Select the folder in question in the Project tool window, and then choose **Tools | Deployment | Sync with Deployed to**  on the main menu.
> 2. In the **Differences Viewer for Folders** that opens, explore the differences and synchronize the files, where applicable.

---

In that [Differences Viewer for Folders](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.3/differences-viewer-for-folders.html) screen you can:

1. See a list of files with differences (or that do not exist of one of the sides) -- top part;
2. Choose any file and see the actual difference/compare them -- bottom part;
3. Also choose to upload/download such file(s) or merge them manually.

[image]
*(screenshot from JetBrains website)*